# MongoDB – Find all docs by array of ids within an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to find any entries in my collection 'groups' where the id of the object in the array 'games' is in an array of ids.

[image: doc example]

The logic in JS:

```
for (const game in games) {
  return game.find(field => field.id.indexOf(arrayOfIds));
}
```

And my idea of logic for mongoose:

```
db.groups.find({ "games.id": { $in: ["5a945...", "1701fa..."] } });
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste sample documents and expected output ?

Comment: @mickl updated it. Is it better to understand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `$elemMatch` to match the array

```
    db.collection.find({
  "games": {
    $elemMatch: {
      id: {
        $in: ["5a945...", "1701fa..."]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/cmphODhmGJg

Comment: That worked! But only when I delete the ObjectId notation from the strings in the array...